# HibernateTemplate initialize replacement with SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I want to replace `hibernateTemplace.initialize(proxy)` to code using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` from Spring 4, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this.

[Hibernate.initialize(proxy)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/)

Refer [this](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/11/forcefully-initializing-proxies-in.html?_sm_au_=iHVJVsMjr7q61qjJ) too.